# Save text from multiple objects depending on bool value

Tags: c#, checkbox, combobox, textbox

I don't know any other way to explain this apart from providing an image of what I'm doing.

[image]

Basically, the Save Cheats button creates a text file that has the information from the 3 textboxes (cheattbox, cheatobox, cheatbbox) numbered respectably. There are 20 total boxes, and to save space only those with data should be saved. Let's say someone wants to save the information from boxes 4, 7, 8 and 13, with those checkboxes checked, I want the text file to only contain information from those given boxes.

Here is the code I have thus far.

```
    public string savemagic(int i)
    {
        CheckBox tickbox = this.Controls.Find("ccheatcbox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;
        TextBox namebox = this.Controls.Find("ccheatname" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
        ComboBox byteselect = this.Controls.Find("ccheatbytebox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as ComboBox;
        TextBox offsetbox = this.Controls.Find("ccheatofsetbox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
        TextBox bytebox = this.Controls.Find("ccheatbytes" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
        fu[i] = string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}\n",namebox.Text, offsetbox.Text, bytebox.Text);
        return fu[i];
    }
    int checkint;
    string[] fu = new string[9999];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog _SD = new SaveFileDialog();
        _SD.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|Show All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        _SD.FileName = "Untitled";
        _SD.Title = "Save As";
        if (_SD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach(var controls in ccheattab.Controls)
            {
                if (controls is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)controls).Checked)
                {
                        string tmp = ((CheckBox)controls).Name.Replace("ccheatcbox", "");
                        checkint = Convert.ToInt32(tmp);
                        File.WriteAllText(_SD.FileName, savemagic(checkint));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try just having the checkbox see if it's ticked or not like so

```
public string savemagic(int i)
{
    CheckBox tickbox = this.Controls.Find("ccheatcbox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;
    if (tickbox.Checked) {
        TextBox namebox = this.Controls.Find("ccheatname" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
        ComboBox byteselect = this.Controls.Find("ccheatbytebox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as ComboBox;
        TextBox offsetbox = this.Controls.Find("ccheatofsetbox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
        TextBox bytebox = this.Controls.Find("ccheatbytes" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
        string Cheats= string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}\n",namebox.Text, offsetbox.Text, bytebox.Text);
        return Cheats;
    }
    return "";
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also, for actually writing to the file, think about using a StreamWriter instead of using File.WriteAllText unless you're going to use a StringBuilder to put these strings together.

This is what happens when you call File.WriteAllText:

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes
>   the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Comment: I got it to read the checked checkboxes using this
http://prntscr.com/7flgn4
but even still it won't print all the selected lines.

Comment: You're trying to write the entire array `fu` in 1 go. You need to loop through the `fu` array and check if it has a non-empty string. If it has a value in it, then write it to the file. Also for neatness, change `Write` to `WriteLine` so it puts each one on a new line. Lastly, make sure the length of `fu` is equivalent to the amount of checkboxes / textboxes you have. You don't have to have to make it a length of 9000 unless you plan on using all of that.

Comment: Hmmmm that's the only part I'm having trouble with, is printing each individual string array in a cohesive fashion. and in my string.Format I included \n for new line :) but I like your idea as well! Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

For a start it would help you a lot if you abstract your model and have a slight separation form UI, it's just going to confuse you when you are dealing with your business logic.

```
class CheatObject {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SelectType { get; set; } // or use enum for this
    public string OffsetStr{ get; set; }
    public string ByteStr { get; set; }

    public ExportToFile() {
        // logic to export a CheatModel
    }
}
...
```

Once you have this, it will be much simpler. Your question could be only, what is the best way to get which rows are checked.

Then: foreach (all checked boxes) cheatModelFromRow.ExportToFile();

Comment: I used this http://prntscr.com/7flgn4 to get what checkboxes were checked, and it works well for me. Now I just need it to save multiple lines to text file rather than just a single line. I'm close, but Can't quite get it! Thank you for your suggestion tho!